# Jest: Mock a nested function which returns key/value pairs multiple times

Tags: jestjs, mocking, nestjs, ts-jest, jest-mock-extended

I am writing a test for an API which calls a nested api multiple times to get a key value pair. The value will always be a `boolean` and I am trying to mock this service aka `KeyValueService` in the code below. These and other more booleans are used in the `PhotoService` and I would like to mock these values so I can change the test to match these values.

I have mocked the booleans and also tried setting `mockResolveValuetwice` to `true` twice thinking that it may apply `true` for both variables `valueA` and `valueB`, but it did not work. I will be using this nested service multiple times and not just twice. So far none of the solutions worked. How can I get a desired value for each key value pair? TIA!

```
jest.mock('../../service/keyValue.service', () => ({
  valueA: false,
  valueB: false
}));

describe('PhotosService', () => {
  let service: PhotosService;
  let keyValueService: KeyValueService;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [PhotosService],
    }).compile();
    
    service = module.get<PhotosService>(PhotosService);
    keyValueService.get.mockResolveValue(() => true);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
    valueA.mockResolveValue(() => true);
  });
});
```

But the values doesnt change. I also tried the following,

```
  it('should be defined', () => {
    keyValueService.get.mockResolveValue(true);
    keyValueService.get.mockResolveValue(true);
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
    valueA.mockResolveValue(() => true);
  });
```

Comment: First thing first, what is the type of valueA and valueB variables?

Comment: Its type `boolean`

Comment: How is your PhotosService using your KeyValueService? Is it a `provider` in your PhotosModule?

Comment: consider it another provider in `PhotoService`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright one thing that worked for me was to set `keyValueService.get` again in  my `test` or `it` block to `jest.fn()` again which worked for me to resolve this issue.

```
keyValueService.get = jest.fn()...;
```

Upto to use what you want. Either `mockImplementation` if need be or `mockReturnValue` etc. My guess is that it just reassigns the `get` function to a new mock value for that particular `it/test` block.